# ASP.NET problem with session / redirect to page

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect

Hi I have problem with store user name in Session. On log on page I store user name to session. User input credentials on logon page and then is redirect on default page. I need in class  Default access to variable store in session.

**Logon.aspx**

```
<script runat="server">
    void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                 Session["user"]  = tbUserName.Text;

                //You can redirect now.
                Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(tbUserName.Text, 
false));
}
</script>
```

secod main page is here:

**Default.aspx-Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Default : Page, 
    IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
{
      string userName = (string) (Session["user"]);
}
```

but result is that userName is empty.

Web config is here:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
```

Thank you for advice.

Comment: In the second page, is that snippet in `Page_Load`?

Comment: You should post complete code to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why not get it directly from HttpContext `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

**Edit:** I guess you are trying to get it at page level instead of in `page_load` or another place. That's why you are not getting a session value.

I hope below will work for you

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string userName = (string) (Session["user"]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the snippet is on the module level (as alluded to by Bala R in the comments) the session state has probably not been set yet.  Try getting it in a method that is part of the page life cycle (like page_load, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is incorrect.

You're losing the (cookieless) session when you redirect. Cookieless sessions are maintained in the URL, and are lost when you explicitly redirect, so there is nothing in the session on your second page.

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation, cookieless sessions are maintained unless the redirection URL is an absolute path, so a relative path should safely keep the session intact. That means it would depend on the redirection destination.